# С чего начать? Что изучать?

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, cms

Добрый вечер.
Появилась "скромная" идея для реализации небольшого проекта (некоммерч., задание: основная цель - получение знаний (изучения каких-либо технологий и тд) + выполнение задания).
Идея: сайт - конфигуратор пк. Стартовый функционал: пользователю предлагается некоторый ассортимент(в идеале, чтение товарных баз магазинов), он выбирает все необходимое, производится проверка совместимости, ну и соответственно итоговая цена (подобное имеется на сайтах и-м комп. техники). А также предложения сборок компьютеров по выбранному бюджету.
Подскажите, с чего начать (что посмотреть, почитать..). С помощью чего реализуется подобное? Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от того, в каком направлении Вы хотите развиваться и как именно хотели бы развиваться.

Под направлением я подразумеваю **frontend** и **backend**.

**Frontend**: это то, что можно "пощупать", то, что "видно", если говорить о языках - это HTML, JavaScript etc, CSS

**Backend**: это уже пощупать нельзя, но серверная работа важна (я бы сказал важнее, чем frontend) - печальное направление, если смотреть "со стороны". Печальное в том плане, что никто не видит этот код, никто не знает, как это работает.

Если взять автомобиль, то фронтенд - внешняя оболочка, стекла, дворники, дисплеи в седушках, а бекенд - двигатель.

> Однако не стоит недооценивать или переоценивать обе стороны. Так как в зависимости от назначения автомобиля, аэродинамика корпуса (фронтенд) может иметь не меньшую значимость, чем двигатель (бекенд), если мы говорим о спортивных авто. Или внешний вид экскаватора (фронтенд) абсолютно не имеет значения по сравнению с его функциональностью (бекенд). То есть это работает в обе стороны в зависимости от задач.

Для начального изучения достаточно начать осваивать HTML и CSS (но не думайте, что CSS - это легко), далее уже можно переходить непосредственно к программированию.

Тут нужно на время забыть про существования языков и изучать общую литературу. А в качестве языка использовать Псевдокод. Псевдокод - это самый верхний по иерархии уровень языков программирования, язык прост - это то, что Вы можете объяснить словами. Например:

```
Человек подходит к краю дороги

Если горит красный сигнал светофора
    Человек ждет
Конец если

Если горит желтый сигнал светофора
    Человек готовится
Конец если

Если горит зеленый сигнал светофора
    Человек переходит дорогу
Конец если

Вернуть положение человека
```

Язык в данном случае неважен, Вы сможете без труда воспроизвести псевдокод на любом языке, главное понимать саму суть программирования.

Если Вы начнете сходу читать книги и статьи по любому языку (не считая CSS и HTML), для того, чтобы научиться, Вы возможно сделаете серьезную ошибку. Потому что учить нужно не язык, а принцип и основы. Язык - это лишь средство

Купите книгу "Совершенный Код" (с) Стив Макконнелл и прочитайте Главу 9. Программируем на Псевдокоде - или найдите эту статью в интернете (но книга тоже важная и нужная)

Кроме того Вам помогут книги Дэвида Макфарланда по CSS, JS, HTML, да и вообще книги серии O'Reilly крайне полезны.

**Самый лучший способ**

Вы уже показали в своем вопросе: начните писать свое. Даже если Вы не знаете как, но хотите, должно получиться. Из чего состоит сайт? то, что видит пользователь - HTML, CSS, JS, то, что не видит пользователь - серверные языки и технологии. Для начала просто создайте сайт на чисто HTML, CSS, JS, когда у вас все получится, задавайте вопрос - `"как создавать динамическую информацию на сайте"` - уверен, ответы в гугле найдутся сразу.

Писать можно еще долго, но я пойду спать, удачи...

Comment: В текущем виде, к сожалению, вопрос задан с нарушениями правил Stack Overflow. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [инициативу Руководств](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/). Было бы крайне здорово, если бы вы смогли переформулировать исходный вопрос в нужном ключе и опубликовать ваш ответ к нему!

Answer (score -1):

Крайне глобальный вопрос(тут такие вопросы запрещены(вроде)), но постараюсь ответить. На создания сайта, нужно знать ЯП(язык програмирования(java например)), уметь верстать html\css, но думаю, вы это уже знаете. Начните с чего душе угодно, но всё же лучше с ЯП. Напишите сервер сайта, потом уже внешний вид. Лично я делаю именно так. Купите или скачайте книжку для начинающих програмистов, и я могу пожелать только удачи!